# Microsoft Access Run time error '3075' in query expression

Tags: sql, database, export

please, I need help, this error happened when I try to export.

sql = sql & " Group By ContactID, TitleID, ContactName, SuffixID, Company, JobTitle, Email1, Email2, Email3, WebPageAddress, IMAddress"
    If Me.chkExportPhone = True Then
        sql = sql & " , PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType "
    End If
    If Me.chkExportAddress = True Then
'        sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType "
         sql = sql & " , AddressLine1 as PostalAddress, AddressLine2 as PostalSuburb,AddressLine3 as StreetAddress, City as Suburb, State, Zip as PostalCode, AddressType "
    End If

```
sql = sql & " , Classification, ClassificationCopy,ReferenceNumber, InvoiceComments,AccountComments,Status,LastContactDate,Notes "
```

Dim qryDef As QueryDef
    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryContactExport")
    **qryDef.sql = sql**
    Set qryDef = Nothing
    'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qryContactExport", "C:\Temp\Temp.xls"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryContactExport", acFormatXLS, Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp.xls", True
End Sub

Visual basic says that the error is this line qryDef.sql = sql.

thanks a lot!

Comment: What value is in your sql variable just before the qryDef.sql = sql line? I think that value will tell you a lot about what the problem is. You can get the value by debugging the code and inspecting the variable. Also, welcome to Stackoverflow - edit your question to fix the formatting since it is nearly impossible to read right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the value
    If Me.chkExportAddress = True Then
'        sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType "
         sql = sql & " , AddressLine1 as PostalAddress, AddressLine2 as PostalSuburb,AddressLine3 as StreetAddress, City as Suburb, State, Zip as PostalCode, AddressType "
    End If

    sql = sql & " , Classification, ClassificationCopy,ReferenceNumber, InvoiceComments,AccountComments,Status,LastContactDate,Notes "

Comment: the error says Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'AddressLine1 as PostalAddress'

Comment: Ah, I think I see something. Let me add as an answer so it is easier to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think this is the problem ( it is kind of hard to tell with just this little snippet to work with. )

Move the marked single quote down one line:

```
sql = sql & " Group By ContactID, TitleID, ContactName, SuffixID, Company, JobTitle, Email1, Email2, Email3, WebPageAddress, IMAddress"
If Me.chkExportPhone = True Then
    sql = sql & " , PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType "
End If
If Me.chkExportAddress = True Then
**'**        sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType "
     sql = sql & " , AddressLine1 as PostalAddress, AddressLine2 as PostalSuburb,AddressLine3 as StreetAddress, City as Suburb, State, Zip as PostalCode, AddressType "
End If

sql = sql & " , Classification, ClassificationCopy,ReferenceNumber, InvoiceComments,AccountComments,Status,LastContactDate,Notes "
```

to

```
sql = sql & " Group By ContactID, TitleID, ContactName, SuffixID, Company, JobTitle, Email1, Email2, Email3, WebPageAddress, IMAddress"
If Me.chkExportPhone = True Then
    sql = sql & " , PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType "
End If
If Me.chkExportAddress = True Then
        sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType "
     ' sql = sql & " , AddressLine1 as PostalAddress, AddressLine2 as PostalSuburb,AddressLine3 as StreetAddress, City as Suburb, State, Zip as PostalCode, AddressType "
End If

sql = sql & " , Classification, ClassificationCopy,ReferenceNumber, InvoiceComments,AccountComments,Status,LastContactDate,Notes "
```

This comments out the incorrect line and replaces it with a good one. The AS keyword in the GROUP BY statement is causing the problem.

Comment: thank you!, but know show me this error. Run-time '3122'
you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression  'StreetAddress' as part of an aggregate function.

visual basic show me this line like error 
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryContactExport", acFormatXLS, Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp.xls", True

Comment: Now is perfect, thank you so much, I just add the AddressLine3 in sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType ".

so thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = sql & " Group By ContactID, TitleID, ContactName, SuffixID, Company, JobTitle, Email1, Email2, Email3, WebPageAddress, IMAddress"
    If Me.chkExportPhone = True Then
        sql = sql & " , PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType "
    End If
    If Me.chkExportAddress = True Then
'        sql = sql & " , AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip, AddressType "
         sql = sql & " , AddressLine1 as PostalAddress, AddressLine2 as PostalSuburb,AddressLine3 as StreetAddress, City as Suburb, State, Zip as PostalCode, AddressType "
    End If

    sql = sql & " , Classification, ClassificationCopy,ReferenceNumber, InvoiceComments,AccountComments,Status,LastContactDate,Notes "

Dim qryDef As QueryDef
    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryContactExport")
    qryDef.sql = sql
    Set qryDef = Nothing
    'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qryContactExport", "C:\Temp\Temp.xls"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryContactExport", acFormatXLS, Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp.xls", True
End Sub
```